# Progress bar with setImageWithURLRequest

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I was wondering if there was a simple way to set up a progress bar for when we download images using AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest. Right now the method does not have a block request.

Any idea?

Comment: I've never used AFNetworking. I could tell you how to do this with NSURLConnection, assuming you know the filesize.

Answer (score 0):

The API for this category is very simple, and doesn't support progress handling right now.  You could [add a progress handler here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.m#L145), like so:

```
[self.af_imageRequestOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    NSLog(@"Received %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);
}];
```

Alternatively, you could use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for your image downloads.  This library is much more advanced (although it's more complex as a result).  It has progress handling, disk caching, and more.